# plupload 2.1.2 does not upload images

Tags: jquery, image-uploading, plupload

I'm trying to install plupload after downloading from the official page https://codeload.github.com/moxiecode/plupload/zip/v2.1.2 but it does not upload images at all though it displays upload complete 100% while on localhost i get this message: HTTP Error. Upload URL might be wrong or doesn't exist.
The index.html is inside the examples folder here's the main code

```
<div id="uploader">
<p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
$("#uploader").plupload({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    url : "/upload",

    // Maximum file size
    max_file_size : '2mb',

    chunk_size: '1mb',

    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    resize : {
        width : 200,
        height : 200,
        quality : 90,
        crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
    },

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip,avi"}
    ],

    // Rename files by clicking on their titles
    rename: true,

    // Sort files
    sortable: true,

    // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
    dragdrop: true,

    // Views to activate
    views: {
        list: true,
        thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
        active: 'thumbs'
    },

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '../js/Moxie.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '../js/Moxie.xap'
});
});
```

And the page online so you can view page source and check http://mawk3y.net/plupload/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folder path error and has been fixed